# Submit a form by clicking href links, without using a submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page where there is search field. the page is designed to have the result on the same page with an id when the submit link is clicked the results will appear below. The submit button is a link not the traditional submit buttons. My problem is i have done all the php stuff but when i click on the link that would let the result appear, the php doesn't run. Could someone please help me out. below is the code. Thanks

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-7 no-padding">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <h3>Track &amp; Trace</h3>
                                    <span>Already have a load ID, please insert it below</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 no-padding">
                                <input class="input-fullwidth" name="track" id="track">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a id="track-it" href="#section-tracking-result" class="btn-custom btn-fullwidth">Track it</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
<?php
     define('DB_HOST','localhost');
     define('DB_USER','username');
     define('DB_PASS','password');
     define('DB_NAME','dbname');

     $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db(dbname) or die(mysql_error());
     $output = '';
     if(isset($_POST['track'])) {
         if(empty($_POST['track'])) {
             echo "Tracking Code is Required";
         }
        $searchq = $_POST['track'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "",$searchq);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM track WHERE keywords LIKE '%$searchq%'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($count == 0) {
             $output = 'There was no search results!';
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                      $consignee = $row['consignee'];
                      $desti = $row['desti'];
                      $date = $row['date'];
                      $id = $row['id'];
            }
        }


    }

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you even have <form> tags for HTML! Make sure you are using them so PHP can make use of the HTML inputs! Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Use form as usual; create a link for submitting form and use onclick="form.submit();" on link

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your html inside a form and you just need to style the traditional submit button.

If you don't want to create a form, you'll probably be able to achieve whatever you're doing here in Javascript.

But PHP needs you to submit using a `<form></form>`

Try this:

`<form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="input-fullwidth" name="track" id="track" />
    <input type="submit" id="track-it" name="submit" class="btn-custom btn-fullwidth" />
</form>`

and in your PHP check if it is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your checks and execution goes here
}
```

This way you check if form is submitted and if the track input is empty then you say that it should not be.

Comment: My friend, KofYebs is using a link instead of normal submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="my_form">
<!-- Your Form -->    
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); return false;">submit</a>
</form>
```

Before that, you have to set a `<form>`

Comment: I've made some changes but still. when i submit the form this is what i get in the address bar. localhost/trackit/#section-tracking-result

Comment: do you added form id, href for a tag & onclick

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit
here a simple button is use, you can use the a tag there.

Comment: here is the link check it out. joemarshipping.com/trackit

Comment: Does anything helped you?